# MFCアプリ（マルチバイト文字セットで作成）からNvarcharのカラムのデータを取得時について

Tags: mfc

マルチバイト文字セットで作成したMFCアプリで
http://7ujm.net/C++/MFC%20ODBC.html
上記のようなプログラムで、ODBC接続してNVARCHARA(unicode）の文字列を取得しようとしています。
特に問題なく、アプリ上で取得して表示できているのですが、
MFCもしくはODBC側でShift-jisに変換しているのでしょうか？
また変換されている場合、変換のON/OFFの切り替えはどこで行うのでしょうか？

Comment: 変換のON/OFFを知りたいのであれば、実際のコードを提示してください。そのコード内で変換されている可能性もあります。

Comment: 上記にリンクを張っていますが、内容は一緒です。ODBC経由でデータベースに接続して取得しています。ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Serverを使用しています。

Comment: 読み込んだ後、`CString`周りの処理で変換している可能性はありませんか？

Comment: そのような処理はないですね

Answer (score 1, accepted):

フィールドデータ取得のために指定した変数の型に応じて変換されているのではないでしょうか？

参照先で「NVARCHARA(unicode）の文字列を取得」しているのはこの部分だと思われますが、
DBアクセス変数定義：

> ```
> //実行
> CRecordset rs( &db );
> ```

途中省略して以下が値取得：

> ```
> //値を表示
> while( !rs.IsEOF() )
> {
>     for(short index = 0; index < rs.GetODBCFieldCount(); index++ )   {
>         CString strValue;
>         rs.GetFieldValue( index, _T( strValue ) );
>         TRACE("%s\n",strValue);
>     }
>     rs.MoveNext();
> }
> ```

`GetFieldValue`仕様のドキュメントでは以下のようになっていて、UNICODE(CStringW), Shift-jisというかANSI(CStringA)の両方サポートされています。

[CRecordset:: GetFieldValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/mfc/reference/crecordset-class?view=msvc-160#crecordsetgetfieldvalue)

> ```
> void GetFieldValue(
>     short nIndex,
>     CStringA& strValue);
>
> void GetFieldValue(
>     short nIndex,
>     CStringW& strValue);
>
> nIndex
> フィールドの0から始まるインデックス。
>
> strValue
> フィールドのデータ型に関係なく、テキストに変換されたフィールドの値を格納するCStringオブジェクトへの参照。
> ```

MFCの`CString`型は、末尾の`A`,`W`が指定されていなければコンパイル時の`UNICODE`,`MBCS`マクロ指定の有無に応じて置換されるはずです。

[CString の使用](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/using-cstring?view=msvc-160)

> オブジェクトは、 CString char wchar_t MBCS シンボルまたは UNICODE シンボルがコンパイル時に定義されているかどうかに応じて、型または型のいずれかをサポートします。

[CStringAクラス、CStringWクラス、CString クラス](http://hp30.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-8.html)

> CStringクラスはプロジェクトの文字セットがマルチバイト文字セットのときはCStringA、Unicode文字セットのときはCStringWにおきかえられるようになっている。
>
> ```
> #ifdef _UNICODE
> typedef CStringW CString;
> #else
> typedef CStringA CString;
> #endif
> ```

---

なので、取得したデータを格納するためのパラメータ変数を、明示的に`CStringA`, `CStringW`で宣言し、`GetFieldValue( index, _T( strValue ) );`呼び出し時の`_T( )`マクロを外して(?)、`GetFieldValue( index, strValue );`のようにすれば、取得するデータのShift-jis/Unicode切り替えが明示的に出来るのではないでしょうか？

**試してみてください。**

Comment: 上記で解決しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

MFCおよびODBCではクエリ結果を変換していないことを確認しました。

- Visual Studio 2019

  - Unicode
  - Multi-Byte
- ドライバ

  - Microsoft SQL Server ODBC ドライバー Version 10.00.19041
  - Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server Version 13.00.0811
  - Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server Version 17.05.0001
  - Microsoft SQL Server Native Client Version 11.00.7462
- データ型

  - `varchar(50)`
  - `nvarchar(50)`

これらの組み合わせで確認しましたが、いずれにおいても、

- `varchar(50)`

  - `CRecordset::GetODBCFieldInfo()` によるカラム型： `SQL_VARCHAR`
  - `CDBVariant` のデータ型： `DBVT_ASTRING`
- `nvarchar(50)`

  - `CRecordset::GetODBCFieldInfo()` によるカラム型： `SQL_WVARCHAR`
  - `CDBVariant` のデータ型： `DBVT_WSTRING`

が得られました。質問文で提示されたサイトでは`CDBVariant` のデータ型として `DBVT_STRING` を処理していますが、そもそもこのデータ型が返されることがありませんでした。

というわけで、受け取ったデータを`CString`で扱っているうちに変換していると思われます。

---

kunifさんが答えられていますが、[`CRecordset::GetFieldValue()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/crecordset-class?view=msvc-160#getfieldvalue)のオーバーロードのうち

- `CString` / `CStringA` / `CStringW` を渡すものは、指定された形式に変換された文字列を得ることができる
- `CDBVariant` を渡すものは、`nFieldType`で受け取る形式を指定できる

  - 更にデフォルトの`DEFAULT_FIELD_TYPE`を使用するとカラムのデータ形式そのままの文字列を得ることができる

となります。ですので

> 変換のON/OFFの切り替えはどこで行う

- Multi-Byte / Unicode特定の型に変換された文字列を取得したい場合

  - `CString` / `CStringA` / `CStringW` を渡す
  - `CDBVariant` を渡しつつ、`nFieldType`を指定する
- カラムのデータ形式そのままの文字列を取得したい場合

  - `CDBVariant` を渡しつつ、`nFieldType`として`DEFAULT_FIELD_TYPE`を指定する

となるかと思います。

---

Visual Studio 2003までさかのぼると、`DBVT_ASTRING` / `DBVT_WSTRING`が存在しなかったようですが…。

Comment: ありがとうございます。自動でデータベースのUnicodeのデータをShift-Jisに変換してしまうということでよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: @userKarasu0807 何を気にされているのかよくわかりませんでした。

Comment: 自分が気にしているのは、自動変換の制御は、設定でONOFF可能かどうかです。調べているのですが、よくわかりませんでした。

Comment: @userKarasu0807 答えて欲しい内容を質問文に記載していただけますか？ 現在の質問文は「変換しているのでしょうか？」となっていますし、私はそれに答えています。

Comment: 変更いたしました。

Comment: ＠sayuri 　nvarcharに漢字を入れたデータであるとどうでしょうか？変換されていませんか？